# Wordpress event onAfterPostUpdated or onAfterPostCreated

Tags: wordpress, events

Is there any way to be registered to wordpress events?
I want to know when a post was updated or created in the system, and get its ID.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the save post hook. It is triggered when the post is created and updated.

Here's a sample.

```
function post_hook( $post_id ) {
      if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
          //Post is being updated
      } else {
         //Post is being created
      }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_hook' );
```

Here's a link from the codex.

[Save Post WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)